# Is it safe to release the parent interface after creating a child interface?

Tags: windows, winapi, parent-child

I am using the `IMMDeviceEnumerator` interface to get all of the `IMMDevice` interfaces. Is it safe to call `Release` on the `IMMDeviceEnumerator` before calling `Release` on the `IMMDevice`? Do any of the IMM interfaces require releasing the child interfaces first?

Comment: yes, this is safe. you can release interfaces in any order

Comment: if class which implemented *IMMDevice* need pointer to class which implemented *IMMDeviceEnumerator* it will be hold internal pointer with reference to it. you not need worry about this internal implementation details. after you got pointer to interface you can use it, until call *Release* on it, independed from any other interfaces